# Sending async emails from a Rake task using Sidekiq on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I am running a sidekiq worker on Heroku and generally I have no problems with the setup:

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

**application.rb**

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

I have a few workers and perform_async is working as expected.
I also have a mailer that gets processed correctly when I call

```
AlertsMailer.favorite_finishing(user).deliver_later
```

I believe Redis to go is setup correctly since everything is working unless ran from the rake task...

The problem is that I want to send these emails using Heroku scheduler and rake task:

```
namespace :scheduler do
  task :alert_finishing_favorites => [ :environment ] do
    users = User.all
    users.each_with_index do | user, index |
      Rails.logger.debug "#{index} Delivering AlertsMailer"
      AlertsMailer.favorite_finishing(user).deliver_later
    end
  end
end
```

When called from the task nothing gets added into my **mailers** queue as is the case when I call the same thing from within the app or from a console...

So the setup is not working only in case of running this as a rake task.

When I run

```
heroku run bundle exec rake scheduler:alert_finishing_favorites -a my-app-name
```

...I get this output:

```
Running bundle exec rake scheduler:alert_finishing_favorites on ⬢ my-app-name... up, run.7112 (Free)
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent in "staging" environment.
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEW_RELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=false environment variable or modify the "staging" section of your newrelic.yml.
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml (/app)
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Environment: staging
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : No known dispatcher detected.
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Application: subasteo-eu-prepro
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing Redis Instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing Sidekiq instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing Memcache instrumentation for dalli gem
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack::Builder instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing Rack::Builder middleware instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing deferred Puma::Rack::Builder instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing Puma::Rack::Builder middleware instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing Rails 3+ middleware instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing ActiveJob instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord 5 instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 Controller instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 Action Cable instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Installing Rails 5 view instrumentation
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:53 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
D, [2017-01-10T11:33:54.681738 #4] DEBUG -- :   Like Load (71.6ms)  SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."value" = $1  [["value", 1]]
** [NewRelic][2017-01-10 11:33:54 +0000 run.* (4)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
```

While In Papertrail I only see this:

```
Jan 10 03:47:32 my-app-name heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/sidekiq/stats" host=my-app-name.herokuapp.com request_id=198a1796-d82f-44e9-a181-82ee954ccf5b fwd="818.217.253.237" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=247ms status=200 bytes=2323 
Jan 10 03:47:33 my-app-name heroku/run.1789:  Awaiting client 
Jan 10 03:47:33 my-app-name heroku/run.1789:  Starting process with command `bundle exec rake scheduler:alert_finishing_favorites` 
Jan 10 03:47:33 my-app-name heroku/run.1789:  State changed from starting to up
```

### **SOLUTION:**

Don't know why `deliver_later` directly form the rake task isn't working, but in the end I decided to create a dedicated worker and call `deliver_now` from within the perform() method. Works as expected...

**Rake**

```
namespace :scheduler do
  task :alert_finishing_favorites => [ :environment ] do
    AlertasFavoritesWorker.perform_async()
  end
end
```

**Worker**
    class AlertasFavoritesWorker

```
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  # sidekiq_options :queue => :pando, :backtrace=> true

  sidekiq_options :retry => 2 # Limit it since we are scraping. Default is 25!!!

  # args are converted into JSON by sidekiq to be saved in Redis
  def perform()
    likes = Like.where(value: 1)
    p "Delivering for #{likes.count} likes!"
    Rails.logger.debug "Delivering for #{likes.count}! likes"
    likes.each_with_index do | like, index |
      Rails.logger.debug "#{index} Delivering AlertsMailer for #{like.user.email}"
      p "#{index} Delivering AlertsMailer for #{like.user.email}"
      AlertsMailer.favorite_finishing(like).deliver_now
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: You do realize that `application.rb` is Rails specific and it's not used by your rake task.

Comment: Hey, yes I know application.rb and other initializers are out of the rake scope, but what I don't know is what excatly do I need to initialize in the task in order to get these mailers onto the queue :\ My task takes the environmnet into consideration so I guess if move the config into staging.rb and production.rb It should set it up correctly... I'll get back to you with the result

Comment: When you run the rake task you can specify the env just like you do in web worker configuration.